# Pandas: Nested Loops & New Column Generation

Tags: python, pandas

[**Goal**] Produce probabilities for various combinations of data.

I want to write a for-loop that does 5 things:

1. Per column, count DISTINCT values of the column.
2. For each DISTINCT value, create a new column, where the name of the column is the column_name + DISTINCT value and append to the end of the df.
3. For each new column, print into each row the percentage that that particular value appears, relative to the original column.
4. Repeat this step for each column to the right of the first column
5. For each DISTINCT new column made, calculate the joint-probability of the value appearing in the column relative to all distinct values of all previous columns to the left.

**[Example]**:

1. col1 has 3 DISTINCT values [1,2,3].
2. 3 new columns are created df['col1_1'], df['col1_2'], df['col1_3']
3. 'col1_1': [.375], 'col1_2': [.375], 'col1_3' : [.25]
4. 'col2_1': [.375], 'col2_2': [.375], 'col2_3': [.25]
5. List item

Initial df

```
df = {
    'col1'  : [1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2], 
    'col2'  : [100,200,300,200,300,300,100,200],
    'col3'  : [25,30,40,25,30,40,25,30],
    'col4'  : ['1k','5k','12k','1k','5k','12k','1k','5k'],
    'col5'  : [700,1400,21,700,1400,21,700,1400]}
```

Output df (spaces added for readability; results view truncated to save space)

```
df = {
    'col1'       : [1,    2,    3,     1,       2,     3,     1,    2], 
    'col2'       : [100,  200,  300,   200,     300,   300,   100,  200],
    'col3'       : [25,   30,   40,    25,      30,    40,    25,   30],
    'col4'       : ['1k', '5k', '12k', '1k',    '5k', '12k', '1k', '5k'],
    'col5'       : [700,  1400,  21,   700,     1400,  21,   700, 1400],
    'col1_1'     : [.375, 0,     0,    .375,    0,     0,    .375,  0], 
    'col1_2'     : [0,    .375,  0,    0,       .375,  0,    .375,  0], 
    'col1_3'     : [0,    0,     .25,  0,       0,     .25,  0,     0],
    'col1_1_100' : [.25,  0,     0,    0,       0,     0,    .25,   0],
    'col1_1_200' : [0,    0,     0,    .125,    0,     0,    0,     0],
    'col1_1_300' : [0,    0,     0,    0,       0,     0,    0,     0],
    'col1_2_100' : [0,    0,     0,    0,       0,     0,    0,     0],
    'col1_2_200' : [0,    .25,   0,    0,       0,     0,    0,     .25],
    'col1_2_300' : [0,    0,     0,    0,       .125,  0,    0,     0],
    'col1_3_100' : [0,    0,     0,    0,       0,     0,    0,     0],
    'col1_3_200' : [0,    0,     0,    0,       0,     0,    0,     0],
    'col1_3_300' : [0,    0,     .25,  0,       0,     .25,  0,     0],
    ''
    ''
    ''}
```

Comment: I've essentially gone through these steps by manually, creating new columns, appending them to the df, and then combining conditions from other columns to get my desired outputs.

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy, I've been "brute-force" doing this. I know that a loop or potentially a function could solve this, but I'm not quite sure what the best way to do it is.